# "Unable to Connect to MySQL Database in Python - Error 2003"

Tags: python, mysql

I'm currently working on a Python script to connect to a MySQL database using the mysql-connector library. However, I'm encountering an 'Error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)'.

```
import mysql.connector

config = {
'user': 'username',
'password': 'password',
'host': 'localhost',
'database': 'mydatabase'
}

connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
```

Expected vs. Actual Behavior:
I expected the script to establish a connection to the MySQL database, but I'm getting the error mentioned above.

Error Messages:
Error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Attempts to Solve:
I've checked my MySQL server status, and it's running. I've also verified the username, password, and database name. I've searched online for similar issues but haven't found a solution that works for me.

Environment/Context:

Python 3.8
mysql-connector-python 8.0.23
MySQL Server 5.7
Additional Information:`
The MySQL server is running on the same machine as my Python script. I can connect to the database using other tools (e.g., MySQL Workbench) without any issues.

Comment: Is it possible that you may need to specify a port?

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference, but you can try using "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost".